# Python Binary Converter

Tags: python, binary

I am new to python and trying to write a binary converter. I want to know if there is a way to check if a value entered is 0 or 1.

Example:

```
binary = userinput
```

check to see if the 8 bit numbers entered by the user are all binary numbers.

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: `value == 0`??? `value == 1`?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one:

```
bin_str = raw_input('Enter a binary number: ')

try:
    bin_num = int(bin_str, 2)
    print "Valid binary number entered. - " + bin_str
except ValueError:
    print "Invalid number entered."
```

Hope that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional statement while looping through all digits of the user input value to check if it's equal to 0 or 1.

Ex.:

```
num = str(input("Insert binary number: "))

for n in num:
    if n == "0" or n == "1":
        print(n, "is a binary digit!")
    else:
        print(n, "is not a binary digit!")
```

Code Output:

```
>>> Insert binary number: 12010104

>>> 1 is a binary digit!
>>> 2 is not a binary digit!
>>> 0 is a binary digit!
>>> 1 is a binary digit!
>>> 0 is a binary digit!
>>> 1 is a binary digit!
>>> 0 is a binary digit!
>>> 4 is not a binary digit!
```

Now you should [ask the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response), that in your case, is a user input with 8 digits.

Answer (score 0):

Another option, presuming that you don't want to actually create an integer and use the exception handling mechanism:

```
all(bit in {"0","1"} for bit in userinput)
```

Comment: or `{"0","1"}.issubset(userinput)` if you really want to use sets.